# Is $F(n)$ completely non-multiplicative?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

*Definition 1:* A function $f$ is said to be completely non-multiplicative, if

$$f(ab)\ne f(a)f(b)$$

for all integers $a,b>1$.

*Definition 2:* define function $F$ as

$$\begin{split}F(n) &=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor \frac{n^k}k\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n^k-1}k\right\rfloor\\ &=\sum_{1\le k\le n\\(n,k)=1} \mu(k)\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor\\ &=|\{k\le n,\ k|n^{(\tau(k)-1)}\}|\end{split}$$

The values of $F(n)$ OEIS- [A010846](https://oeis.org/A010846)

> *Question:*
>
> Can it be shown that function $F$ is completely non-multiplicative?

$\\$
*Example:*

Let $a=2$, $b=10$, $ab=20$.

We have $F(20)=8$, $F(10)=6$, $F(2)=2$, and
$8\ne 6\cdot 2$.

If $n=prime$, then $\left\lfloor \frac{n^k}k\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{n^k-1}k\right\rfloor$ for $1<k<n$ implies $F(n)=2$.

---

Another related post on non-multiplicative [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3447525/647719).

If you have any reference to non multiplicative please share.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware, desmos gives wrong results for this function, for example it calculates $f(17)$ to be 1 instead of the correct result which is 2. https://i.imgur.com/Cj6vYv6.png. This is a simple floating point calculation error, but I found it really unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: $F(18)=10=2\cdot5=F(3)F(6)$.

A brute force search over just $2\le a\le b\le100$ already finds 31 counterexamples.

Comment: And I tout, I'm good in claims. But now i learn its my stupidness. thanks for your time to go through it and solution too.:-)